# How can I repeat a character to make up a string if I have a number for the times to repeat?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
vm.Points = phrase.Points.ToString();
```

I would like to replace it with something that would put an X character as many times as there are phrase.Points where phrase.Points is an integer.

So if phrase.Points has a value of 5 then I would like the value of vm.Points to be "XXXXX"

Comment: Look at [PadRight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
new String('X', phrase.Points);
```